# How can I tell which libstdc++ double-conversion wants?

Tags: haskell, ubuntu, ghci

Here's the error I see when trying to load a .hs file into ghci.

```
>Loading package http-enumerator-0.7.1.1 ... linking ... done.
>Loading package double-conversion-0.2.0.1 ... can't load .so/.DLL for: stdc++ ?>>>     (libstdc++.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

Further investigation reveals I have multiple stdc++ libraries installed

```
>locate libstdc++.so
>/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
>/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
>/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/libstdc++.so
>/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6
>/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
```

I thought maybe I could make a symlink to what it wants, but I have no idea which one. I'm using this OS
2.6.35-22-server #33-Ubuntu SMP Sun Sep 19 20:48:58 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux

How can I tell exactly what it wants?

Comment: Also: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5289

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ones in `/usr/lib` symlink to one file:

```
$ ls -l libstdc++*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      19 2011-09-24 22:14 libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.13
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1044112 2010-03-26 20:16 libstdc++.so.6.0.13
```

Just run:

```
sudo ln -si /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib/libstdc++.so
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6` should be a symlink to `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14`. This is probably the version you need.

`/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6` should be a symlink to `/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6.0.14`, they are for 32-bit programs, you don't normally need them.

`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/libstdc++.so` is the problem.

`double-conversion-0.2.0.1` probably has got linked against it, and `ghci` cannot find it. Normally everything should be linked against `libstdc++.so.6`, not `libstdc++.so` without a version suffix.

I *think* one should not have a version-less `libstdc++.so` at all anywhere in the system. (There's none on my gentoo box for example.) It is dangerous, as different major versions of `libstdc++` are usually binary incompatible. Try removing the library you have under `/usr/lib/gcc/`, then reinstall `gcc` and see if it gets installed again.

If it does get installed, then a symlink named `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so` pointing to `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6` *should* solve this problem. I'm not sure this would be the right way to solve it in the long run though.

These are things I have found through experiments with my own Linux box. I am not an expert in Ubuntu, it may do things differently from other Linuxes.

Answer (score 1):

To work around the issue on 64-bit Fedora 16:

```
sudo ln -si /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so
```