# Could someone offer troubleshooting steps for resolving a possible package conflict?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Here's the error ghci throws when I try to run my program.

```
>Loading package primitive-0.3.1 ...

>GHCi runtime linker: fatal error: I found a duplicate definition for symbol
>memset_off
>whilst processing object file
>/home/mlitchard/.cabal/lib/primitive-0.3.1/ghc-7.0.3/HSprimitive-0.3.1.o
>This could be caused by:
>* Loading two different object files which export the same symbol
>* Specifying the same object file twice on the GHCi command line
>* An incorrect `package.conf' entry, causing some object to be
> loaded twice.
>GHCi cannot safely continue in this situation.  Exiting now.  Sorry.
```

Here's the source, followed by what I think this problem is.

```
>import Network.HTTP.Enumerator
>import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
>import Data.ByteString
>import Data.Attoparsec.Enumerator (iterParser)
>import Data.Aeson
>import Data.Attoparsec
>import Data.Maybe
>import Network.URI
>import Network.HTTP

>main :: IO ()
>main = do
>req <- openURL "https://pkg.cudaops.com/cgi-bin/qaLinkEditor.cgi?json=1"
>print $ parse json req

>openURL :: String -> IO ByteString
>openURL url = getResponseBody =<< simpleHTTP (mkRequest GET (fromJust $ parseURI url))
```

I have two versions of primitive.0.3.1 and  0.4.0.1

```
>0.3.1 is needed by aeson 0.3.2.12
>0.4.0.1 is needed by http-enumerator-0.7.1.1
```

ghc-pkg has revealed I have a whole mess of broken packages. Perhaps I should delete ghc and cabal and start from scratch?

Comment: If you post a minimal example (or the whole source) together with the exact ghci invocation, it is much easier to give a solution. As of now, your question basically says "I get this error, guess what I could have done wrong." There are so many possible errors and sadly my crystal ball has a crack that renders it unusable.

Comment: This turned out to be a side-effect of a problem with textual-blaze.   The textual-blaze github site gave a workaround for another problem I was having. When I followed their instructions, instead of what I was doing to resolve the problem, the above problem went away. Perhaps I should post a more complete answer as a lesson to always read the documentation provided?

Comment: If you solved the problem, you should post it as an answer and accept it. (This is not considered sleazy -- this site is about fixing problems, and it doesn't matter who fixes it so long as it gets fixed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from an incorrect solution to this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761880/how-can-i-tell-which-libstdc-double-conversion-wants)

[Here](https://github.com/mailrank/aeson#readme) is the actual problem causing this trouble, with reference to the solution.

Comment: mailrank pulled their public repos. I'll see if I can find it in the aeson repo. Edit: I'll take this problem to the mailing lists.